# Any LaTex editor that have auto formating feature?

Tags: editors

I tried many different editors and surprising non of them has such basic function. Please tell me an editor that I can auto format and indent all the lines by a click or hotkey.

Comment: You may need `latexindent` which is contained in TeX Live.

Comment: vim/gvim can do automatic indenting of LaTeX without plugins or calls to external formatting tools (but if you are unhappy with the result you can also use a plugin or call an external formatting tool).